# node-sass and react-scripts error while installation

Tags: reactjs, npm

I can not install my npm project due to dependency errors. Node-sass and react-scripts both say high vulnerabilities.

[image]

Here is my npm audit report.
How can I solve it?

```
   nth-check  <2.0.1
Severity: high
Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in nth-check - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-rp65-9cf3-cjxr
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install react-scripts@2.1.3, which is a breaking change
node_modules/svgo/node_modules/nth-check
  css-select  <=3.1.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of nth-check
  node_modules/svgo/node_modules/css-select
    svgo  1.0.0 - 1.3.2
    Depends on vulnerable versions of css-select
    node_modules/svgo
      @svgr/plugin-svgo  <=5.5.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of svgo
      node_modules/@svgr/plugin-svgo
        @svgr/webpack  4.0.0 - 5.5.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/plugin-svgo
        node_modules/@svgr/webpack
          react-scripts  >=2.1.4
          Depends on vulnerable versions of @svgr/webpack
          node_modules/react-scripts



scss-tokenizer  *
Severity: high
Regular expression denial of service in scss-tokenizer - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-7mwh-4pqv-wmr8
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install node-sass@4.5.3, which is a breaking change
node_modules/scss-tokenizer
  sass-graph  >=2.2.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of scss-tokenizer
  node_modules/sass-graph
    node-sass  >=4.6.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of sass-graph
    node_modules/node-sass

terser  5.0.0 - 5.14.1
Severity: high
```

Comment: node-sass is deprecated use [dart-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass)

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/12132#issuecomment-1130249584), if you are using node >= 16 you can install last version of @svgr/webpack

```
npm i -D @svgr/webpack
```

In which case you have to add a line in your package.json

```
"overrides": {
    "@svgr/webpack": "$@svgr/webpack"
}
```

Remove `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` then perform a new `npm install`.

You could also only upgrade the 'nth-check' library in a similar fashion.

The library "node-sass" is [deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass) so you may use another library, or identify and upgrade the failing component in a similar way as above.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the suggestion that @Zitoun provided. However, if your application has required input fields with a focus function when submitting with empty fields using `react-hook-form`, the suggestion will break your app - `.focus is not a function`. Please check your form before using the suggestion in your production!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33254944)